# Run function after one function is complete - JQuery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple jquery animate function running on click, what I want is, run a function after animation is complete, This is how I am doing, code below:

This is how my code is doing, on button click, four div appearing from bottom to top (default the div is in -100% bottom position), each div have content, expected result is, appear the content after all the four div loaded, which is not happening right now.

**UPDATE**

This is the [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/yryff2yq/4/)

Only requirement is to show the div content once all the four columns loaded.

```
$(".menuitem-2").click(function() {
    $(".wwasection-one").stop(true, true).delay(2000).animate({
            bottom: 0
        }, 3000,
        function() {
            $(".wwa-gallery-content").stop(true, true).delay(18000).css("opacity", "0.4");
        });
    $(".wwasection-two").stop(true, true).delay(4000).animate({
            bottom: 0
        }, 5000,
        function() {
            $(".wwa-gallery-content").stop(true, true).delay(22000).css("opacity", "0.4");
        });
    $(".wwasection-three").stop(true, true).delay(5000).animate({
            bottom: 0
        }, 8000,
        function() {
            $(".wwa-gallery-content").stop(true, true).delay(32000).css("opacity", "0.4");
        });
    $(".wwasection-four").stop(true, true).delay(7000).animate({
            bottom: 0
        }, 10000,
        function() {
            $(".wwa-gallery-content").stop(true, true).delay(42000).css("opacity", "0.4");
        });
});
```

Comment: Try setTimeout function.

Comment: Try setTimeout function.

Comment: Content? what content? where should it appear?

Comment: Are you trying to change `opacity` of `".wwa-gallery-content"` after all `bottom` property animations have completed?

Comment: Yes exactly, I am trying to change the opacity of `.wwa-gallery-content` after all the animation completed.

Comment: I know that this is out of jquery but I would advice to use GSAP tweenmax. TimelineMax is perfect with your animation. And it's very easy to learn. It's like counting numbers from 1-10.

Comment: @LaraBelle thanks for your input, actually I am planning to use GSAP as its smooth as compared to jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain `.promise()` to `.animate()` calls passed to `$.when()` to perform task at `.then()` chained to `$.when()` after all `.animate()` calls have returned resolved jQuery promise.

```js
var winw = $(document).width();
var winh = $(document).height();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".whoweareWrapper").height(winh);
  var settings = [
    {delay:2000, duration:3000},
    {delay:4000, duration:5000},
    {delay:5000, duration:8000},
    {delay:7000, duration:10000}
  ];
  $(".menuitem-2").click(function() {
    $.when.apply($, $.map($("[class~=wwasection]"), function(el, index) {
        return $(el).stop(true, true).delay(settings[index].delay)
               .animate({bottom: 0}, settings[index].duration).promise()
      }))
      .then(function() {
        $(".wwa-gallery-content").css("opacity", "0.4");
      })
  });
});
```

```css
.whoweareWrapper {
  width: calc(100% - 130px);
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.wwasection {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  border-right: 1px solid #f00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wwasection-one {
  background-color: #cdcdcd);
  left: 0;
}

.wwasection-two {
  background-color: #bdbdbd);
  left: 25%;
}

.wwasection-three {
  background-color: #c0c0c0);
  left: 50%;
}

.wwasection-four {
  background-color: #b0b0b0);
  left: 75%;
}

.wwa-opacity-mask {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .5s linear;
  -ms-transition: all .5s linear;
  -o-transition: all .5s linear;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

.wwa-gallery-content {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.wwa-gallery-content>h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
}

.wwa-gallery-content>p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
}

.wwa-opacity-mask:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.wwa-opacity-mask:hover .wwa-gallery-content {
  opacity: 0.7 !important;
}

.wwa-discover-btn {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

.wwa-discover-btn>a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.wwa-discover-btn>a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333333;
}

.wwa-opacity-mask:hover .wwa-gallery-content>.wwa-discover-btn {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gall-wrapper2" class="whoweareWrapper">
  <a href="#" class="menuitem-2">Show Div</a>
  <!-- Block One -->
  <div class="wwasection wwasection-one">
    <div class="wwa-opacity-mask">
      <div class="wwa-gallery-content">
        <h1>JOURNEY </h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <div id="discover1" class="wwa-discover-btn"> <a href="#">Discover</a> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="arrowdown" id="wwa-gallery-detail1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Block Two -->
  <div class="wwasection wwasection-two">
    <div class="wwa-opacity-mask">
      <div class="wwa-gallery-content">
        <h1>PROJECTS DONE </h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <div id="discover1" class="wwa-discover-btn"> <a href="#">Discover</a> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="arrowdown" id="wwa-gallery-detail1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Block Three -->
  <div class="wwasection wwasection-three">
    <div class="wwa-opacity-mask">
      <div class="wwa-gallery-content">
        <h1>FOUNDER INFO </h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <div id="discover1" class="wwa-discover-btn"> <a href="#">Discover</a> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="arrowdown" id="wwa-gallery-detail1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Block Four -->
  <div class="wwasection wwasection-four">
    <div class="wwa-opacity-mask">
      <div class="wwa-gallery-content">
        <h1>PRESS & ACCREDIATIONS </h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <div id="discover1" class="wwa-discover-btn"> <a href="#">Discover</a> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="arrowdown" id="wwa-gallery-detail1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After reaching of `last div` to `top:0` i.e. `.wwasection-four` you could change content `opacity` back to `1`, as below,

```js
 var winw = $(document).width();
 var winh = $(document).height();
  $(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".whoweareWrapper").height(winh);
  $(".menuitem-2").click(function() {
  $(".wwasection-one").stop(true, true).delay(2000).animate({
    bottom: 0
   },3000 ,
  function() {
    $(".wwa-gallery-content").css("opacity", "0");
   });
  $(".wwasection-two").stop(true, true).delay(4000).animate({
    bottom: 0
   },5000,
   function() {
    $(".wwa-gallery-content").css("opacity", "0");
   });
  $(".wwasection-three").stop(true, true).delay(5000).animate({
    bottom: 0
   }, 8000,
      function() {
    $(".wwa-gallery-content").css("opacity", "0");
   });
  $(".wwasection-four").stop(true, true).delay(7000).animate({
    bottom: 0
   }, 10000 ,
      function() {
    $(".wwa-gallery-content").css("opacity", "1");
   });
 });
});
```

```css
.whoweareWrapper {
 width: calc(100% - 130px);
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
.wwasection {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 bottom: -100%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 25%;
  border-right:1px solid #f00;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.wwasection-one {
 background-color: #cdcdcd);
 left: 0;
}
.wwasection-two {
 background-color: #bdbdbd);
 left: 25%;
}
.wwasection-three {
 background-color: #c0c0c0);
 left: 50%;
}
.wwasection-four {
 background-color: #b0b0b0);
 left: 75%;
}
.wwa-opacity-mask {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s linear;
 -moz-transition: all .5s linear;
 -ms-transition: all .5s linear;
 -o-transition: all .5s linear;
 transition: all .5s linear;
}
.wwa-gallery-content {
 max-width: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 vertical-align: middle;
 top: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
.wwa-gallery-content > h1 {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 34px;
 font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin: 0;
}
.wwa-gallery-content > p {
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
}
.wwa-opacity-mask:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.wwa-opacity-mask:hover .wwa-gallery-content {
 opacity: 0.7 !important;
}
.wwa-discover-btn {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 opacity: 0;
}
.wwa-discover-btn > a {
 font-size: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 8px 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.wwa-discover-btn > a:hover {
 background: #fff;
 color: #333333;
}
.wwa-opacity-mask:hover .wwa-gallery-content > .wwa-discover-btn {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gall-wrapper2" class="whoweareWrapper"> 
 <a href="#" class="menuitem-2">Show Div</a>
 <!-- Block One -->
  <div class="wwasection wwasection-one">
    <div class="wwa-opacity-mask">
      <div class="wwa-gallery-content">
        <h1>JOURNEY </h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <div id="discover1" class="wwa-discover-btn"> <a href="#">Discover</a> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="arrowdown" id="wwa-gallery-detail1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Block Two -->
  <div class="wwasection wwasection-two">
    <div class="wwa-opacity-mask">
      <div class="wwa-gallery-content">
        <h1>PROJECTS DONE </h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <div id="discover1" class="wwa-discover-btn"> <a href="#">Discover</a> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="arrowdown" id="wwa-gallery-detail1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Block Three -->
  <div class="wwasection wwasection-three">
    <div class="wwa-opacity-mask">
      <div class="wwa-gallery-content">
        <h1>FOUNDER INFO </h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <div id="discover1" class="wwa-discover-btn"> <a href="#">Discover</a> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="arrowdown" id="wwa-gallery-detail1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Block Four -->
  <div class="wwasection wwasection-four">
    <div class="wwa-opacity-mask">
      <div class="wwa-gallery-content">
        <h1>PRESS & ACCREDIATIONS </h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <div id="discover1" class="wwa-discover-btn"> <a href="#">Discover</a> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="arrowdown" id="wwa-gallery-detail1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation for [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> .animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )

Where complete is:

> **complete**
>   Type: [Function()](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Function)
>   A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.

So you could define a function that you increments a counter and when the counter reaches 4 then all animations should be completed.