# When the page is loaded,how to make six functions executed by each otherr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, delay

When the page is loaded , in a big div, there are six different elements and there are six different functions for the elements.I want to make the functions execute by each other after a sure time for example 1000ms.But the six functions are not bind to one elements ,they are binded to six different elements.
For example, when the page is loaded,I want addClass "line1" to element "#linear1", after 1000ms, removeClass ".line1" from element "#linear1", 
and immediately, 
addClass "line2" to element "#linear2", after 1000ms, removeClass ".line2" from element "#linear2", 
and immediately,
addClass "line3" to element "#linear3", after 1000ms, removeClass ".line3" from element "#linear3"
...
addClass "line6" to element "#linear6", after 1000ms, removeClass ".line6" from element "#linear6"
then back to "#linear1"..."linear6"...loop

jquery(".cspaceintro is a parent div for middlecolumn"):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".cspaceintro").load(function(){
   $("#linear1").addClass("line1");

   //here,I don't know what to do next..

})
})
```

html:

```
<div class="middlecolumn">
                <div class="left1">
                    <div id="linear1"  ></div>
                </div>
                <div class="left2">
                    <div id="linear2" ></div>
                </div>
                <div class="left3">
                    <div id="linear3" ></div>
                </div>
                <div class="right1">
                    <div id="linear4" ></div>
                </div>
                <div class="right2">
                    <div id="linear5" ></div>
                    <!-- <div class="point"></div> -->
                </div>
                <div class="right3">
                    <div id="linear6" ></div>
                </div>
```

part of css

```
.line1{
float: right;

width: 0%;
height: 3px;
background-color: #2e9edd;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#2e9edd), to(#2e9edd));

-webkit-animation:aaa 1s linear 1;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
}
.line2{
float: right;
position: relative;
top:30px;
width: 0%;
height: 3px;
background-color: #2e9edd;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#2e9edd), to(#2e9edd));

-webkit-animation:aaa 1s linear 1;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;

}
.line3{
float: right;
position: relative;
top:50px;
width: 0%;
height: 3px;
background-color: #2e9edd;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#2e9edd), to(#2e9edd));

-webkit-animation:aaa 1s linear 1;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
}

@keyframes aaa{

0%  {width:0%; }
30% {width:30%; }
60% {width:60%; }
100%{width:95%; }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see any function here in the code

Comment: You can use `css` to achieve expected result. Can you include what have you tried to solve inquiry at `css` or `javascript` at Question?

Comment: See [Run function after one function is complete - JQuery animate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555971/run-function-after-one-function-is-complete-jquery-animate/43556139#43556139)

Comment: @brk ,I add what I write in jquery file.

Comment: @guest271314 I just upload some jquery code, very simple

Comment: Have you read linked Question and Answer? Why is `animation` property defined at `css`, though no `@keyframes` rules are defined at `css`?

Comment: _"... addClass "line6" to element "#linear6", after 1000ms, removeClass ".line6" from element "#linear6" then back to "#linear1"..."linear6"...loop"_ There are only three `.lineN` declarations at `css`. The `background` property value should be `-webkit-linear-gradient`, not `-webkit-gradient(linear`

Comment: @guest271314  yeah, I would fix this .The line4,line5,line6, I didn't upload them.

Comment: @LTulip You can use `.queue()`, `.promise()`, `.then()`, `animationend` event; see post. Remove `.slice(0, 3)` call if more than three `.lineN` declarations are  added to `css`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.queue()` to queue a function to be called for each element in an array or jQuery object. Set `.className` at element, attach `animationend` event to element using `.one()`, at `animation` end handler called when `css` animations complete for the element, remove `.className`, call next function in queue.

Chain `.promise()`, `.then()` to `.dequeue()`  to  call function when all functions in queue have been called and jQuery returns promise object.

At `.then()` function set `width` of `#linearN` element to `"0%"`, call original function again, repeatedly, at  `.then()` chained to `.promise()` when queue is empty of functions, to satisfy "loop" requirement of scheduling same function to be called following asynchronous function calls.

The Question describes six `#linearN` elements

> ... addClass "line6" to element "#linear6", after 1000ms, removeClass
>   ".line6" from element "#linear6" then back to
>   "#linear1"..."linear6"...loop

though there are three `.lineN` declarations at `css`, not six. Only first three `#linearN` elements are passed to function at stacksnippets. When six `.lineN` declarations are defined at `css`, remove `.slice(0, 3)` chained to `$("[id^=linear]", middlecolumn)`.

```js
$(function() {

  var middlecolumn = $(".middlecolumn");
  var linearLines = $("[id^=linear]", middlecolumn).slice(0, 3);

  function animateLines(column, lines) {
    return column.queue("lines", $.map(lines, function(el, index) {
        return function(next) {
          $(el).addClass("line" + (index + 1))
            .one("animationend", function() {
              $(this).removeClass("line" + (index + 1));
              setTimeout(next, 1000);
            })
        }
      })).dequeue("lines").promise("lines")
      .then(function() {
        console.log("lines queue complete"
        , "\n`animateLines` call scheduled at next line");
        return animateLines(column, lines.css("width", "0%"));
      })
  }

  animateLines(middlecolumn, linearLines);

})
```

```css
.line1 {
  float: right;
  width: 0%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #2e9edd;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0 0, 0 100%, from(#2e9edd), to(#2e9edd));
  -webkit-animation: aaa 1s linear 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.line2 {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  width: 0%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #2e9edd;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0 0, 0 100%, from(#2e9edd), to(#2e9edd));
  -webkit-animation: aaa 1s linear 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.line3 {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: 0%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #2e9edd;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0 0, 0 100%, from(#2e9edd), to(#2e9edd));
  -webkit-animation: aaa 1s linear 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes aaa {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  30% {
    width: 30%;
  }
  60% {
    width: 60%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 95%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="middlecolumn">
  <div class="left1">
    <div id="linear1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="left2">
    <div id="linear2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="left3">
    <div id="linear3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right1">
    <div id="linear4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right2">
    <div id="linear5"></div>
    <!-- <div class="point"></div> -->
  </div>
  <div class="right3">
    <div id="linear6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```