# JQuery. apply css to each element with a class using delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've just take a look on a lot of answer on stack but nothing seems can work on this.
I'me trying to apply a style to all element of a list `li` sequentially using delay. The script show just the last item of the list. What's the problem? thanks in advance for your help

```js
$('ul li').each(function(i){
licont = this
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(licont).css('opacity','1')
  },i * 10);                  
});
```

```css
li{
  opacity:0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>ITEM 1</li>
  <li>ITEM 2</li>
  <li>ITEM 3</li>
  <li>ITEM 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think you left out the variable declaration in line 2, can you edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the current element as a jQuery object as a parameter to `setTimeout` to reference current jQuery object within `.each()` when function passed to `setTimeout` is called

```js
$('ul li').each(function(i) {
  setTimeout(function(el) {
    el.css('opacity', '1')
  }, i * 1000, $(this));
});
```

```css
li {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>ITEM 1</li>
  <li>ITEM 2</li>
  <li>ITEM 3</li>
  <li>ITEM 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking a better way to pass the current element to child functions for other applications also.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? What are "child functions"?

Comment: See also [Execute function queue in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028368/execute-function-queue-in-javascript), [When the page is loaded,how to make six functions executed by each otherr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567064/when-the-page-is-loaded-how-to-make-six-functions-executed-by-each-otherr/)

Comment: I was using a var licont = this to pass the current element inside the setTimeout function. I think your is a better way to do it. I mean I was looking for this.